# Trouble in registration to Bluemix with my IBM ID

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I tried to register my IBM ID to Bluemix, I have troubled.
In detail, I went to the page by clicking 'SIGN UP' and 'Already have an IBM ID?', and I registered with entering my phone number and e-mail address. But, an error occurred.

After your response, I cam tell my IBM ID and email address in a not public way.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix is currently experiencing issues in the US Production environment.

Please refer to the [Status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) to get some information on the outage.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Platform(US-SOUTH) is under a maintenance.
The information is here.
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Your issue may be related with this maintenance.
Please re-try after this maintenance.